# How to get maxlength/pattern value of a simpleType in an XSD

Tags: c#, xml, recursion

I want to traverse an xsd in order to get each attribute's type and after that that type's value but I am stuck in just retrieving the type.

So far I have successfully traversed the xsd tree via recursion

```
private int GetFieldMaxLengthValue(XmlSchemaObject element)
        {
            if(element is XmlSchemaComplexType)
            {
                var complextType = element as XmlSchemaComplexType;

                if(complextType.Particle == null)
                {
                    var attributes = complextType.Attributes;

                    foreach (var attribute in attributes)
                    {
                        var schemaAttribute = attribute as XmlSchemaAttribute;
                        var attributeSchemaType = schemaAttribute.SchemaTypeName.Name;


                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    GetFieldMaxLengthValue(complextType.Particle);
                }
            }
            else if(element is XmlSchemaSequence)
            {
                var sequence = element as XmlSchemaSequence;

                foreach (XmlSchemaObject item in sequence.Items)
                {
                    var schemaType = item as XmlSchemaElement;
                    GetFieldMaxLengthValue(schemaType.SchemaType);
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

And here is the simpleType's value (maxLength) i want to retrieve:

```
 <xs:simpleType name="String100">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="100" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

I need to get the value 100 and save it in a variable for later use.

In the piece of code I provided look at the first foreach loop. We get there once we get to an complexType which has no other children as complexTypes. So we have reached the last complexType with its only children xs:attributes. Now, as I cast the attributes I can retrieve the name and type. But what I need is to gather the type's value from the constraint provided last in the code piece.

**P.S** I know that i could take the type's name " string100" and substring it to get the 100 and parse it to int, but what if this is not the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been available the whole time and it look simple:

```
using (XmlReader schemaReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(the_schema_as_string)))
        {
            XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
            schemaSet.Add(XmlSchema.Read(schemaReader, null));

            var xsdAsXDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(the_schema_as_string));
            var ns = XNamespace.Get(@"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

            foreach (XmlSchemaElement element in schemaSet.Schemas()
                .Cast<XmlSchema>()
                .SelectMany(s => s.Elements.Values.Cast<XmlSchemaElement>()))
            {
                GetFieldMaxLengthValue(element, xsdAsXDoc, ns);
            }
        }
```

The element you retrieve from the foreach has a property "Parent" and as you click the parent from there you can find the whole types. Before I was directly stuck to the root element and the whole time I was supposed to go to the parent and from there to search for the simple types!

Answer (score 1):

I used a vary large schema and parsed the xsd into a tree structure recursively using xml linq.  See solution below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ParseSchema
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xsd";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xs");

            Element element = new Element(null, root, ns, null);
            SimpleContent.LinkParents();
            Element.LinkParents();

        }
    }
    public class Element
    {
        public static List<Element> elements = new List<Element>();  // needed to link to parent

        public XNamespace ns { get; set; }
        SchemaType schemaType { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object> typeDictionary = null;
        public Dictionary<string, string> attributeDictionary = null;
        public Element parent { get; set; }
        public string annotation { get; set; }

        public Element(SchemaType parentSchema, XElement parentXElement, XNamespace ns, Element parentElement)
        {
            XElement xAnnotation;
            XElement xElement;

            this.parent = parentElement;
            this.ns = ns;
            Element.elements.Add(this);


            List<XElement> xTypes = parentXElement.Elements().Where(x => (x.Name.LocalName == "simpleType") | (x.Name.LocalName == "complexType")).ToList();

            foreach (XElement xType in xTypes)
            {
                string name = (string)xType.Attribute("name");
                if (typeDictionary == null) typeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                SchemaType newType = new SchemaType(xType, ns, this);
                typeDictionary.Add(name, newType);
            }

            xElement = parentXElement.Element(ns + "element");
            attributeDictionary = xElement.Attributes()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (string)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            xAnnotation = xElement.Element(ns + "annotation");
            if (annotation != null) annotation = (string)xAnnotation.Element(ns + "documentation");

        }
        public static void LinkParents()
        {
            foreach (Element element in elements)
            {
                string stringType = "";

                Boolean foundAttributeType = element.attributeDictionary.TryGetValue("type", out stringType);
                if (foundAttributeType && !stringType.StartsWith("xs:"))
                {
                    Element parent = element;
                    object obj = null;
                    while (parent != null)
                    {
                        if (parent.typeDictionary != null)
                        {
                            Boolean foundType = parent.typeDictionary.TryGetValue(stringType, out obj);
                            if (foundType)
                            {
                                element.schemaType = (SchemaType)obj;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        parent = parent.parent;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
    public class SchemaType
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string simpleComplex { get; set; }
        public string annotation { get; set; }
        public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
        public Restrictions restriction { get; set; }
        public SimpleContent simpleContent { get; set; }
        public Element parentElement { get; set; }
        public List<Element> elements { get; set; }

        public SchemaType(XElement schemaType, XNamespace ns, Element parentElement)
        {
            simpleComplex = schemaType.Name.LocalName;

            foreach (XElement child in schemaType.Elements())
            {
                switch (child.Name.LocalName)
                {
                    case "annotation":
                        annotation = (string)child.Element(ns + "documentation");
                        break;
                    case "attribute":
                        Attribute newAttribute = new Attribute(child, ns, parentElement);
                        if (attributes == null) attributes = new List<Attribute>();
                        attributes.Add(newAttribute);
                        break;
                    case "restriction":
                        restriction = new Restrictions(child, ns);
                        break;
                    case "sequence":
                        elements = child.Elements(ns + "element").Select(x => new Element(this, child, ns, parentElement)).ToList();
                        break;
                    case "simpleContent" :
                        simpleContent = new SimpleContent(child, ns, parentElement);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

    }
    public class Restrictions
    {
        string baseType { get; set; }
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> enumerations { get; set; }

        public Restrictions(XElement xRestriction, XNamespace ns)
        {
            baseType = (string)xRestriction.Attribute("base");
            enumerations = xRestriction.Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (string)y.Attribute("value"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
        }
    }
    public class Attribute
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> attributeDictionary;
        public string annotation { get; set; }
        public SchemaType schemaType { get; set; }

        public Attribute(XElement attribute, XNamespace ns, Element parentElement)
        {
            attributeDictionary = attribute.Attributes()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (string)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            XElement xAnnotation = attribute.Element(ns + "annotation");
            if (annotation != null) annotation = (string)xAnnotation.Element(ns + "documentation");

            List<XElement> xSchemaType = attribute.Elements().Where(x => (x.Name.LocalName == "simpleType") | (x.Name.LocalName == "complexType")).ToList();
            if(xSchemaType.Count > 0) schemaType = new SchemaType(xSchemaType.FirstOrDefault(), ns, parentElement);

        }
    }
    public class SimpleContent
    {
        public static List<SimpleContent> contents = new List<SimpleContent>();  // needed to link to parent
        public string baseType { get; set; }
        public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
        public SchemaType schemaType { get; set; }
        public Element parentElement { get; set; }

        public SimpleContent(XElement content, XNamespace ns, Element parentElement)
        {
            this.parentElement = parentElement;
            contents.Add(this);
            XElement extension = content.Element(ns + "extension");
            if (extension != null)
            {
                baseType = (string)extension.Attribute("base");
                List<XElement> xAttributes = extension.Elements(ns + "attribute").ToList();
                foreach (XElement xAttribute in xAttributes)
                {
                    if (attributes == null) attributes = new List<Attribute>();
                    Attribute newAttribute = new Attribute(xAttribute, ns, parentElement);
                    attributes.Add(newAttribute);
                }
            }

        }
        public static void LinkParents()
        {
            foreach (SimpleContent content in contents)
            {
                if (!content.baseType.StartsWith("xs:"))
                {
                    Element parent = content.parentElement;
                    object obj = null;
                    while (parent != null)
                    {
                        Boolean foundType = parent.typeDictionary.TryGetValue(content.baseType, out obj);
                        if (foundType)
                        {
                            content.schemaType = (SchemaType)obj;
                        }
                        parent = parent.parent;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out! My tech lead also suggested me doing something similar! I will give a feedback on this post after I work it out!