# how to create custom ssis component which used to convert xml data to oledb destination

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

i want to develop a Custom SSIS Component which takes XML document path from local machine and then read that XML Document according to that if there is root node then loop through the document and select root node also loop through different parent element and there respective child elements.
With the help of XML file i want it automatically generate table column and fields that i want to then transfer to OLE DB Destination.

i am trying it with a sample XML Document but i don't know the correct way to read the XML file and according to that make column and datatypes for OLE DB Destination

Here is my code for that particular component
it is the method which

```cs
public DataTable GetRSSDataTable(String xmlpath)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlpath);
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(reader);

        dt.Columns.Add("Title", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        //dt.Columns.Add("pubDate", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
        dt.Columns.Add("URL", Type.GetType("System.String"));

        foreach (XmlNode node in document.DocumentElement)
        {
            DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
            dRow["Title"] = node.InnerText;
            //dRow["PublishDate"] = node.Attributes[1].ToString();
            dRow["URL"] = node.InnerText;
            dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
        }

        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

}

public void AddOutputColumns(String propertyValue)
    {
        DataTable dt = GetRSSDataTable(propertyValue);
        if (dt != null)
        {
            //Check if there are any rows in the datatable
            if (dt.Rows != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataTable schemaDT = dt.CreateDataReader().GetSchemaTable();
                foreach (DataRow row in schemaDT.Rows)
                {
                    IDTSOutputColumn100 outputCol = ComponentMetaData.OutputCollection[0].OutputColumnCollection.New();

                    bool isLong = false;
                    DataType dType = DataRecordTypeToBufferType((Type)row["DataType"]);
                    dType = ConvertBufferDataTypeToFitManaged(dType, ref isLong);
                    int length = ((int)row["ColumnSize"]) == -1 ? 1000 : (int)row["ColumnSize"];
                    int precision = row["NumericPrecision"] is System.DBNull ? 0 : (short)row["NumericPrecision"];
                    int scale = row["NumericScale"] is System.DBNull ? 0 : (short)row["NumericScale"];
                    int codePage = schemaDT.Locale.TextInfo.ANSICodePage;

                switch (dType)
                {
                    case DataType.DT_STR:
                    case DataType.DT_TEXT:
                        precision = 0;
                        scale = 0;
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_NUMERIC:
                        length = 0;
                        codePage = 0;
                        if (precision > 38)
                            precision = 38;
                        if (scale > precision)
                            scale = precision;
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_DECIMAL:
                        length = 0;
                        precision = 0;
                        codePage = 0;
                        if (scale > 28)
                            scale = 28;
                        break;
                    case DataType.DT_WSTR:
                        precision = 0;
                        scale = 0;
                        codePage = 0;
                        break;
                    default:
                        length = 0;
                        precision = 0;
                        scale = 0;
                        codePage = 0;
                        break;
                }

                outputCol.Name = row["ColumnName"].ToString();
                outputCol.SetDataTypeProperties(dType, length, precision, scale, codePage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remaining is the same code which we use to make any custom component

Actually i want to know which is the best way to read data in XML file in local machine and second thing according to that information how to create output columns and data in that columns which required to pass to OLE DB Destination. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried using for-each container in ssis?

Comment: I parsed a schema last week recursively to get similar results. See my answer at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56809278/how-to-get-maxlength-pattern-value-of-a-simpletype-in-an-xsd/56818365#56818365

Comment: @EdBangs no but i want to write code for custom component which does this whole thing so i can use only that

Comment: Before you start writing custom components, get a basic script solution working first.